# Why does compressed & zipped/unzipped file geodatabase give Open Failed Error opening feature class Cannot access secured data?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.2, file-geodatabase, compression

In ArcGIS 10.2 for Desktop, a colleague compressed a file geodatabase and then zipped it and sent it to me via email.

I unzipped it and was unable to add any of the feature classes into my map document.

I received this error: "Open Failed. Error opening feature class. Cannot access secured data."

I uncompressed it in ArcCatalog and got the same error when trying to add the data to ArcMap.

This also happened when the colleague zipped the uncompressed geodatabase.

Comment: Try using the GP Compact tool. Sometimes this can help remove lock files if they were accidentally sent with the FGDB.

Comment: @Mintx Compact may not get the same reduction in size as Compress but if lock (*sr.lock*) files are the problem then the asker may be able to look for and delete them in the file geodatabase folder via Windows Explorer.

Comment: No sr.lock files.  It looks like transferring via Dropbox uncompressed is no problem. But any use of the Compress tool seems to corrupt it somehow.

Comment: I have experienced the same error. I've used ArcPy to do a whole bunch admin things (which work) on 1 of 3 feature class in a 10.1 fGDB. I then compress the fGDB and the whole thing goes pear shaped. I can't retrieve the data by any means once it's compressed.